# Finding domain of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{|\sec x|}-\frac{\cos x}{|\csc x|}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

> Find the domain of
>   $$f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{|\sec x|}-\frac{\cos x}{|\csc x|}$$

In my view domain should not be where $\sec x$ and $\csc x$ will be 0 which is never. So domain is $\mathbb R$. But textbook states it wrong. Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: Domain is set of all real numbers except the numbers where ANY of denominators is zero. This means that you exclude all $x$ such that $\sec x = 0$ OR $\csc x = 0$.

Comment: @MaliMish they are never zero. i know their graphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When $x$ is *not* an integer multiple of $\frac\pi2$, all the trigonometric functions present give well-defined and non-zero results, so $f$ is also well-defined.
- When $x$ is an *even* multiple of $\frac\pi2$, $\sin x=0$ and $\csc x=\frac1{\sin x}$ is undefined. This alone is enough to cause $f$ to be undefined.
- Likewise, when $x$ is an *odd* multiple of $\frac\pi2$, $\sec x=\frac1{\cos x}=\frac10$ causes $f$ to be undefined.

Hence the domain of the given function is $\Bbb R\setminus\{\frac{k\pi}2\mid k\in\Bbb Z\}$.

Comment: But graphs of $|sec(x)|$ and $|csc(x)|$ is not zero anywhere

Comment: @J.Deff Yes, but what if $|\sec x|$ and $|\csc x|$ are _themselves_ undefined? Then the function can't be defined, right?

Comment: Oh i see that, you mean to say i have to remove their asymptotes

Comment: @J.Deff Yes. Remove the places where either of the two functions diverges to infinity.